# The use and historical authenticity of a 9 hook broadsword

Tags: kung-fu, sword

I've recently bought a [9 hook broadsword](https://www.kungfudirect.com/prodimages/TDS/Dao/9-hooksword-b.jpg) from an online martial arts store. I bought it mainly for decoration, but as an ex kung fu practioner and a general sword enthusiast I want to know how it is meant to be used, and preferably try out a few techniques myself.

I thusly went ahead and searched for an answer, but unfortunately it seems that the references to this weapon are scarce; except for one or two more stores which sell the weapon I didn't find any reference to it even existing at all.

This is why I came here. I wonder if this is a weapon that's existed historically, and if there are any references to its use if it is? Also, if it is a historical weapon but there are no real manuals on how to use it, could it be assumed that it was used similarly to a 9 ring broadsword?

Comment: I suspect it is very similar except for the addition of hooks which I imagine can be used to cut or catch things as you pull back. It's a move I've seen people in the system I practice but with a regular 9-ring broadsword. I haven't seen this variation on this weapon before though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have any references, only anecdotes from instructors I've trained with, so please do not mistake this as historically accurate information.

The picture you show appears to be a variation on the 9 Ring Broadsword.  This is supposed to have been a training weapon.  The 9 Rings on the back of the blade provide a sound that assists the student in knowing the quality of the strike.  When slashing, the rings should click together **consecutively** with 9 distinct clicks, one after the other.  When thrusting, all the rings should click at the same time, ensuring a powerful thrust.  The added benefit of distracting the opponent should be apparent.

As you've noted, the weapon is similar to the 9 Ring Broadsword, and I think it should be treated as a variation of the same.  My guess is that you'll get more hits on 9 **Ring** Broadsword than 9 Hook Broadsword.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It sounds to me that what you say might well be true. I will start looking for references and manuals of the 9 ring broadsword instead then!

Comment: @Psyberion, the weapon that you show is a good deal wider than the average broadsword.  It reminds me a bit of the guandao (polearm) blade, moreso than a traditional broadsword.  Perhaps the added weight of the blade adds to the training benefit?  Good luck in finding what you need and please let us know what you find.

Comment: Yes, it is. I'd estimate that it's about 9cm closest to the guard, and about 15-20cm at it's broadest. And I agree, it does resemble a guandao, even in blade length. Thank you once again, I will keep you posted if I discover something!

Answer (score 0):

My sifu taught me that the purpose of these rings is changing the weight and balance of your broadsword. By changing the number and order of the rings, the student can practice with different weight/balance, so the student can use almost every broadsword in his hand.

Comment: The question is asking about a sword with hooks, not rings, and whether this sword is similar to one with rings. It is not asking for an explanation of the rings.